# How to change the width and height of a Telerik RadWindow control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

This is my code :

```
<telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager2" runat="server">
    <Windows>
        <telerik:RadWindow ID="RadWindow1" Height ="500px" Width="600px" Left="100px" Top="100px" runat="server" Modal="true" OnClientClose="OnClose" OnClientShow="OnOpen">
        ...
        </telerik:RadWindow>
    </Windows>
</telerik:RadWindowManager>
```

This is how I open the RadWindow

```
function Func() {
    window.radopen(null, "RadWindow1");
}
```

But anyways the window width and height is staying as default. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a reference to the dialog and set its dimensions via JavaScript:

```
var oWnd = $find("<%= DialogWindow.ClientID %>");
oWnd.show();
//Here set the width and height of RadWindow
oWnd.setSize(400, 400);
```

This could happen in the OnClientShow event too.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party here but the dimensions values should not contain units. Ditch the "px" for the declared attributes.

Answer (score -1):

you need to change the behavior of the window, you can set it on property or change it on code behind . try it , I am not sure:

```
RadWindow1.Behaviors = Telerik.Web.UI.WindowBehaviors.Resize
```

http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/window/getting-started/user-interaction-with-the-window

Comment: it doesnt have any property to change the width or height